# D Compiler for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, d

I am just getting into D, and I'm trying to figure out if I can use D for programming an Arduino. I know D normally compiles to native binaries, but I haven't had any luck trying to find a D compiler for the AVR instruction set. Does anyone know of a method for compiling D code for the Arduino?

Comment: Your best bet would be gdc http://gdcproject.org/downloads/ but I don't think anyone has worked on it.. i've done x86 and arm but never avr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a D compiler that can target ATmega328. As Adam pointed out, GDC is your best bet, but I haven't seen anyone using it for Arduino development. I am sure GDC developers will welcome contributions towards this goal.

Building GCC that targets ATmega328 is easy nowadays. You will also need [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/). Ask on the [D forum](http://forum.dlang.org/) - maybe someone was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino usually uses a 8 bit AVR chip and I have never seen a D compiler (DMD, LDC, GDC) which can generate 8 bit code.